# Is it possible to nest VPN connections?

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to create an VPN connection while using site-to-site VPN?

Have you ever tried or done this?

What are possible problems, pitfalls, things of the impossible, etc. ?

Also see: [Is it possible to use Microsoft's "Secure Connection Rules" (IPSec) with VPN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/126537/is-it-possible-to-use-microsofts-secure-connection-rules-ipsec-with-vpn)

Comment: While it's possible, there's probably a better way. What are your requirements that you think a nested VPN is the solution?

Comment: There are no requirements, I just wanted to see if it is possible and what the pitfalls are.
For an implementation related question visit the link.

Comment: Yep, it'll work. You just incur all the cost of VPNs x2 (lower MTU, higher latency, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely to start having issues related to MTU, but yes, it can work.

Whether it will work depends on what exact combination you're hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is.  read [this very complete explanation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/447/8171) on combining tor and vpn nesting.

then read [this vpn nesting workflow](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46923/11533).